# Why does a dot product of two masked vectors in numpy return an oddly shaped array?

Tags: numpy, masked-array

I have the following code:

```
result = np.ma.dot( array1, masked_array2 )
```

Which gives something like this:

```
masked_array(data = 24.681441709536468,
         mask = False,
         fill_value = 1e+20)
```

result.data.shape gives:

```
()
```

I can access the value by converting it to a float, like

```
float(result.data)
```

Is this the correct way of accessing the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a 0D tensor.

Typically numpy converts 0D tensor to native type

```
type(np.dot([1,2], [3,4])) # gives 'int'
```

However, when the result is masked array, due to the existence of mask, there's no way to convert it directly to a native type without losing information. Thus you get a "oddly shaped" 0D tensor as result.

Yes, you can access it by converting it to float.